# Why does Xcode "does not conform to protocol fix-it" adds many methods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode9

Xcode has a new "fix-it" feature for automatically implementing protocol methods. Here is an example:

[image]

`MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` has only a single method. However, when I click "fix" button, Xcode creates *MANY* irrelevant method stubs:

[image]

I haven't added any new other protocols, it's just as follows:

```
@interface TUDiscoverInviteViewController ()<CNContactPickerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

My view controller only derives from `UITableViewController`. Where are those method stubs coming from and how can I prevent this behavior?

I'm on Xcode 9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewController` conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`, so you get those method stubs too.

I don't see a way to get Xcode to only generate stubs for one protocol, except by temporarily removing the other protocols and changing your base class.

If you use [AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/), then you can use AppCode's Code > Generate > Implement Methods interface to select which members you want stubs for:

[image: appcode generate window]

Comment: Uhm, I don't have AppCode. I can delete them, sure, I was just curious why it's happening. You're right about table view protocols, but what about all the others e.g. `setFocusUpdate`, `encodeWithCoder:`, trait collection methods etc.?

Comment: Oh wait, just answered myself by checking out `UIViewController` class: `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UIViewController : UIResponder <NSCoding, UIAppearanceContainer, UITraitEnvironment, UIContentContainer, UIFocusEnvironment>`

Comment: @rob : not every user has access to an IDE !

Comment: That is why I said "If you use AppCode”, not “Use AppCode”.

Comment: @robmayoff could you extend your answer to make it more clear that the fix-it function creates explicit stubs for ALL the superclasses, even if they are already implemented as in `UIViewController` for clarification for future users?